# http request and if problem

Tags: http, node.js

So i have to make a http request call only if the user enters lat,lng in the inputs, so that means on the server side I have to check if that input was set or not. If it was, then I want to add this data, plus some more data to the database. If not set, then I want to save only the some more data to the database.

Right now I am running the same code in if{} and in else{}. Is there a way for me to avoid that?

Comment: Please clarify, we are willing to help, but clarify more. If possible, show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstract out the code inside of your `if` and `else` statements and make it a function that takes an object and persists it to the database.  Then call that function, passing in the response object (or an alternate object, if you are doing some work beforehand.)

```
function persist_data(response) {
    // Do work to set up the database
    database.save(response);
}

function respond_to_user_input(req, res) {
    var response = {};
    // Populate the necessary data into the response object
    if (user_has_provided_lat_and_lng) {
        // Set up your response object to include lat an lng
        persist_data(response);
    } else {
        // Include only the *other* data
        persist_data(response);
    }
}
```

There are **most likely** already tools out there to help you with what you are doing -- if you show a bit of what you are trying to do this answer can get a *lot* less generic. :-)

Answer (score 1):

you only need to test if both args, lat and lng have info. In both cases you have to save allData or someData.
So, the best way to do this is (IMHO):

```
var lat = (lat != '') ? lat : 0;
var long = (lng != '') ? lng : 0;

saveDataToDB(lat, long, somedata);
```

So if the values are 0 or '', you save a 0 (thinking that both values are numbers)